# get one random value after php query fetch rows from the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following mysql table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `reg_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

In this table there are some values as follows

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `reg_number`) VALUES('qaser', 'j-001'), ('rizwan', 'j-002'), ('rizwan', 'j-003'),('rizwan', 'j-004'),('rizwan', 'j-005'),('rizwan', 'j-006'),('rizwan' 'j-007'),('rizwan', 'j-008');
```

I am retrieving these values using the following query

```
$sql="SELECT reg_number FROM users";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(!$result){
            die(mysqli_error($con));
           }
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['reg_number'];
}
```

It gives me the following output

```
j-001 j-002 j-003 j-004 j-005 j-006 j-007 j-008
```

It goes very well as the these queries run. I want random output of this result which will be only one value eg. j-005

as the rand(1,8) function work it gives only one value.

Comment: `SELECT reg_number FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @Class I have used it but show all values randomly. I want only one value from these to show on the page.

Comment: did you also use `LIMIT 1` because it limits the results of the search

Comment: @Class oh sorry I forgot that thank you very much you make my life easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use RAND() operand to do that

```
SELECT reg_number FROM users ORDER BY RAND() limit 1
```

Comment: I have used it but show all values randomly. I want only one value from these.